# Creating groups with Firebase Realtime Database in Android app

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have an Android app that uses the Firebase Realtime Database. At the moment it is a single user app, in that when a user logs in, using Firebase Auth, the data they create is kept private to them. What I need to do for the next phase of the project is to allow for the creation of teams or user-groups that have access (read and write) to the data currently created by a single user.

The database structure and rules for doing this are understood, however, the issue I have is how to create the groups.

I did find the following blog and it is very close to what I need, it does not make clear how a new user would create the pending membership entry in a specific "chat" (this is a group chat sample).

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/group-security-in-firebase-database.html

Any points on resolving this final issue would be much appreciated.

Sid

Answer (score 1):

Just simply create groups like below

```
|--Groups
    |---group1
           |-----uID1 - owner
           |-----uID2 - participant
           |-----uID3 - participant
 ..............
```

follow this https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/group-security-in-firebase-database.html link. There are example groups and rules. It will help for u to proceeds it.

Follow this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data to make good structure of data to increase performance

Comment: Thank you, as I said in my question I know how to structure the database and rules. The question is  how a new user would create the pending membership entry in a specific "chat" (in the linked group chat sample)

Comment: Seems I forgot to include the article link, the question is edited now.